# Why does the Diophantine equation $6xy-3x-2y+1=0$ have no solution in $ \mathbb{Z}^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Consider the function $f(x,y)= 6xy-3x-2y+1$.

**Question**: Why does the Diophantine equation $f(x,y)=0 $ have no solution in $ \mathbb{Z}^2$?

---

I have seen a few questions like this on this page..but still couldn't figure out what the trick is here..

appreciate any help!

Comment: You should use correct spelling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x,y)=(3x-1)(2y-1)$ is this is $0$ only when $x=\frac  1 3$ or $y=\frac  1 2$.

Comment: Please strive not to post further dupe answers to FAQs - this complicates site organization.