# prove that congruence has a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let be $ f(x,y)= 6xy-3x-2y+1 $

How can I show that the congruence $ f(x,y) \equiv 0 \pmod m  $

has a solution in $ \mathbb{Z}^2 $ for any $ m \in \mathbb{N} $?

I know from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452868/showing-a-diophantine-equation-has-no-solution) that we can factor $f$ as $(3x-1)(2y-1)$ but I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Note: The function $f$ can be factored into the product of $2$ simple linear factors.

Comment: You have asked this already, i.e., the factorisation, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3452868/showing-a-diophantine-equation-has-no-solution).

Comment: yeah right, in $ f(x,y)= (3x-1)(2y-1) $

Comment: @DietrichBurde No, this is differeent since it is **$\bmod m$**

Comment: @BillDubuque The factorisation of this  polynomial was already known to the OP, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ Let $\,m = 2^kn,\ \color{#c00}{n\ \rm odd}.\,$ To solve $\,2^k n\mid (3x\!-\!1)(2y\!-\!1)^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!$ it suffices to solve $\, 2^k\mid 3x\!-\!1\,$ & $\,n\mid 2y\!-\!1^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!,\,$ i.e. $\,x\equiv 3^{-1}\!\pmod{\!2^k}\,$ & $\, y \equiv 2^{-1}\!\pmod{\!n}^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!;\,$ both exist by $\,(3,2^k)\! =\! 1\! =\! \color{#c00}{(2,n)}^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!$

**Remark** $ $ The factorization follows from:  completing a *square* [generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/651073/242) to completing a *product*, using the AC-method, viz.
$$\begin{eqnarray} &&axy + bx + cy\, =\, d,\ \ a\ne 0\\
\overset{\times\,a}\iff\, &&\!\! (ax+c)(ay+b)\, =\, ad+bc\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: Does AC stand for something, or it’s named after the coefficients a and c?

Comment: @J.W.T  Likely the name derives from the coefficient names. I knew the [general method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647116/242) long before I learned that some high-school teachers had a name for this special case, so I didn't have a chance to investigate it way back when I was more interested in math history (and had more spare time).